# Replace characters in a string using conditional formatting R

Tags: r

I have a word list as in `wordlist` below:

```
 wordlist <- data.frame(words = c("anywhere", "youll", "feel", "comfortable", "please", "dont"))
```

I have another dataframe with a list of consonants:

```
 consonants <- data.frame(consonants = c("b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h"))
```

I want to create a new variable in `wordlist` called `word_structure`, where all consonants are replaced with `"C"`, and all vowels with `"V"`:

```
 wordlist$word_structure <- c("VCCCCVCV", "CVVCC", "CVVC", "CVCCVCCVCCV", "CCVVCV", "CVCC")
```

I can't work out how to combine conditional formatting with `gsub` to get what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar as shown by @[stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12993861/stefan), in your case, you could write:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tibble(
  words = c("anywhere", "youll", "feel", "comfortable", "please", "dont"),
  you_want = c("VCCCCVCV", "CVVCC", "CVVC", "CVCCVCCVCCV", "CCVVCV", "CVCC"),
  you_get = str_replace_all(str_replace_all(words, "[aeiou]", "V"), "[^V]", "C")
)

## A tibble: 6 × 3
#  words       you_want    you_get    
#  <chr>       <chr>       <chr>      
#1 anywhere    VCCCCVCV    VCCCCVCV   
#2 youll       CVVCC       CVVCC      
#3 feel        CVVC        CVVC       
#4 comfortable CVCCVCCVCCV CVCCVCCVCCV
#5 please      CCVVCV      CCVVCV     
#6 dont        CVCC        CVCC
```

Answer (score 7):

This seems a better fit for `chartr()` than `gsub()`:

```
vowels <- c("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")
consonants <- letters[!letters %in% vowels]

wordlist$word_structure <- chartr(
  old = paste(c(vowels, consonants), collapse = ""),
  new = paste(c(rep("V", 5), rep("C", 21)), collapse = ""), 
  wordlist$words)

wordlist

        words word_structure
1    anywhere       VCCCCVCV
2       youll          CVVCC
3        feel           CVVC
4 comfortable    CVCCVCCVCCV
5      please         CCVVCV
6        dont           CVCC
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `stringr::str_replace_all` which allows to replace multiple patterns you could do:

Note: Instead of you incomplete list of consonants I used a vector of the five vowels.

```r
wordlist <- data.frame(words = c("anywhere", "youll", "feel", "comfortable", "please", "dont"))

vowels <- c("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")

patterns <- setNames(
  c("C", "V"),
  c(
    paste0(c("[^", vowels, "]"), collapse = ""),
    paste0(c("[", vowels, "]"), collapse = "")
  )
)
patterns
#> [^aeiou]  [aeiou] 
#>      "C"      "V"

stringr::str_replace_all(
  wordlist$words,
  patterns
)
#> [1] "VCCCCVCV"    "CVVCC"       "CVVC"        "CVCCVCCVCCV" "CCVVCV"     
#> [6] "CVCC"
```

Answer (score 1):

Splitting the strings and matching

```
sapply(
  strsplit(wordlist$words,""),
  function(x){
    paste0(c("V","C")[(strsplit(x,"") %in% consonants$consonants)+1],collapse="")
  }
)
[1] "VVVVCVVV"    "VVVVV"       "CVVV"        "CVVCVVVVCVV" "VVVVVV"      "CVVV"
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R

```
> gsub('[^aeiou]', 'C', words) |> gsub(x=_, '[aeiou]', 'V')
[1] "VCCCCVCV"    "CVVCC"       "CVVC"        "CVCCVCCVCCV" "CCVVCV"      "CVCC"
```

stringi

```
> stringi::stri_replace_all_regex(words, c('[^aeiou]', '[aeiou]'), c('C', 'V'),
+                                 vectorize_all=FALSE)
[1] "VCCCCVCV"    "CVVCC"       "CVVC"        "CVCCVCCVCCV" "CCVVCV"      "CVCC"
```

---

*Data:*

```
words <- c("anywhere", "youll", "feel", "comfortable", "please", "dont")
```